# My site cant be accessed from certain ISPs

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

I am on a VPS hosted by a company in Europe. I can access my site normally, many other people i know can as well. However in the recent days i have received reports from many other people that say they cant. They get a timed out request error page. The common denominator seems to be they all have the same ISPs. I have had reports from several different countries such as Spain, Peru, Argentine etc. What can be happening?

Comment: You will probably need to [share the actual hostname](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) of the site in order to get this resolved. You should also share any other information you may have available, such as that you have already been asked for.

Comment: You mean my actual domain?

Comment: Yes, the _real_ information, not fake information.

Comment: IS it okay if i put it on an image and i post the link?

Comment: I had a similar problem years ago where the IP address of the site was one that had only recently been allocated and was still on the [bogon list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogon_%28address%29) where I worked.  This may or may not be your problem, but we can't check without knowing the IP. The same goes for the domain. Image and link is fine if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a routing problem. Ask them to traceroute your server's IP, and ask them to ask their ISP what's going on.

That's probably nothing that you can fix from your side.

Comment: So this is definitely a problem with my host and not my domain?

Comment: This is a problem with the connection between that ISP and your Host. (I suspect)

Comment: A>nd it can be anywhere - your host, the other end ISP, some point in between so one or both sides have to change their BGP routing.

Comment: The wierd thing is that its not only one ISP, but more than one in different countries. However, I and many other people have no problems so i really dont get it.

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to troubleshoot them carefully with traceroutes and stuff from affected clients. You can also try one of the traceroute services out there which allow you to trace sited from multiple locations: https://www.google.ch/#q=traceroute+multiple+locations

Comment: hi, i just asked somebody who has the problem to do it and he gets: timeout request unknown

Answer (score 2):

We ran into a similar problem in the past.
This is incredibly hard to debug.

What we did:
Created a unique whatever.txt file on our domain and asked the users to request it.
That way we were able to see if our heavy app was having a problem and this request still reached us. It didn't.

Asked the users to perform DNS queries and traceroutes to our public IPs.
One of them was using a Mac, was cooperative and ran some `curl` requests and provide the output to us.
At that point it was clear that it was a routing issue.
Until then we were unsure if the users computers might have been compromised/hijacked, but with this information we were confident that this wasn't the case.

Your best course of action is contact your hosting company with this information and get them to escalate it.
We also tried contacting the problematic ISP directly, but ultimately it was impossible to ever speak to someone who understood the problem - that might of course be different in your case.

Comment: I thought i could be a problem with the company that manages my domains because i have 4 pointing to different servers hosted by different companies and all of them have the same problem.

Comment: Do all 4 domains use the same DNS server? Still could be a routing issue, just not to your webserver but to the DNS server.

Comment: No, i have 4 domains, 3 of them point to the same server but different directories and a 4th one forwards to a site on a completely different server. But i received reports from users that cant access any of the 4 while i and many other users can.